# How to rewrite a param url as a directory in NextJS without changing page on refresh?

Tags: javascript, next.js

Ok, so it's probably very simple, but I can't figure it out.

Whenever I type /login in the url I just want to stay at the home page and not redirect to /pages/login (404 for now). I also need to keep it as a GET param to toggle my LoginModal.

```
import Link from 'next/link'

// components/Header.js
<Link href="/?login" as="/login">
   <LoginButton />
</Link>

// components/Auth.js
const Auth = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    return (
        <>
            { 'login' in router.query && <LoginModal />}
            { 'register' in router.query && <RegisterModal />}
        </>
    )
}

// pages/index.js
const Index = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <HomePage />
      <Auth />
    </>
  )
}

// pages/login.js doesn't exist
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved in NextJS update 9.5 with Rewrite
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites

```
// nextjs.config.js

module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/login',
        destination: '/?login',
      },
      {
        source: '/register',
        destination: '/?register',
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

It's working perfectly like that.